# Function executed without being called for

Tags: python

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        super().__init__(length, width)
        length = int(input("Length of the square: "))
        width = int(input("Width of the square:"))

    def area(self):
        print(Square.length * Square.width)


class Cube(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        super().__init__(length, width)
        length = int(input("Length of the cube: "))
        width = int(input("Width of the cube:"))
        self.height = int(input("Height of the cube: "))

    def volume(self):
        print(Cube.length * Cube.width * Cube.height)


Square = Square(3, 3)
Cube = Cube(3, 3, 3)

Square.area()
# Cube.volume()
```

Thought i did not call the `Cube.volume` method, the output is printing the inputs given in the `Cube` class.

Comment: Why does your constructor prompt the user for the `length` and `width` parameters, but also accepts them as arguments? You are also using static variable access and assignment (`ClassName.property_name`) instead of instance variable access and assignment (`self.property_name`)...

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code... I suggest reading up on some of the [fundamentals of OOP with Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Comment: `Square = Square(3, 3)` Don't reuse variables like that, especially between instances and their classes. Rename it to something like `square = Square(3, 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cube` really shouldn't subclass `Rectangle` for various reasons. This may be opinion-based, but you really ought to have two base classes `Rectangle` for all 2D rectangles, and `Cuboid` for all 3D rectangular boxes. Then you can subclass each with the special cases of `Square` and `Cube`:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length: int, width: int) -> None:
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(size, size)


class Cuboid:
    def __init__(self, length: int, width: int, height: int) -> None:
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def volume(self):
        return self.length * self.width * self.height


class Cube(Cuboid):
    def __init__(self, size: int):
        super().__init__(size, size, size)
```

Notice that instance variables are set in the constructor, and at no point are any class variables used. For reference, an instance variable is any time you see code like `self.some_property`, and a class variable is any time you see code like `ClassName.some_property`. Generally speaking, the later is used much less often, and only for very good reasons. For an object *with properties that should change for every instance of that object* (like the width of a rectangle's side, or the hair color of a dog), you should not be using class variables.

It's also generally not good practice to prompt for user input upon object instantiation.

As I mentioned in my comment, I strongly recommend reading up on the [fundamentals of OOP in Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) as there are a number of conceptual misunderstandings present in your code.